# How can I pull latest posts, with unique authors, so that if an author wrote two posts in a row, it only gets the first?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

So right now, I have Posts and Authors... I want to make a "20 recent posts" section at my website.

Sometimes an author makes 4-5 posts in a row. In the 20 latest posts, I want all of these posts to have unique authors. So if author A wrote last 3 posts based on created_at, I only want the last post.

Hypothetically:

A wrote  posts 10, 9, 7
B wrote posts 8, 6
C wrote posts 5, 1
D wrote posts 4, 3, 2

Then in the latest 4 posts section, I'd like posts: 10, 8, 7, 6

Or in any other manner where the author ID is unique, and I have 20 latest posts.

I've tried Post.select(:author_id).distinct, mapping, and other bits here and there, but I'm not sure if I'm going the right direction.

Thanks guys.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, you want last 20 posts with no two consequent posts of the same author, right ?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't even have to be two consequent posts, or anything like that. What I provided is a hypothetical situation. In reality, an author can sometimes have 100-200 posts in a row, and they tend to take up the entire "recent posts" section of the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general idea.  You can fill in the details.

```
 select author, maxts, etc
 from sometables join
 (select authorId, max(timestamp_field) maxts
 from etc
 where whatever
 group by authorId) temp on temp.authorId = author.authorId
 and sometable.timestamp_field = maxts
 where whatever
```

Make sure the "where whatever" is the same in both places.